# A basic UnicodeEncodeError issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Writing a basic scraping script. I fail to comprehend where I keep going wrong. I faced the same issue when I was using python 2.7.

I use Sublime 3 as my text editor
I use macOS
I run python3.6

Here is what I have so far:

```
import bs4

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://wbsite.com'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#loop starts here

#base of the script,

one = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"large-7 medium-9 columns"})
two = page_soup.findAll("div",{"body field"})
three = page_soup.findAll("div",{"field-ingredients-data field-wrapper"})
four = page_soup.findAll("div",{"field-how-to-use-data field-wrapper"})



onito = (one[0].h1)
docito = two[1]
trincipito = (three[0].p)
cuatrocinto= (four[0].p)


filename = "insertfilehere.cvs"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "onito, docito, trincipito, cuatrocinto\n"

f.write(headers)

un = str(onito.text)
deux = str(docito.text)
trois = str(trincipito.text)
quatre = str(cuatrocinto.text)


base = (un + "," + deux + "," + trois + "," + quatre + "\n")
encoding_base = base.encode("utf-8)")
finito = encoding_base.decode("utf-8)")

f.write(finito)

f.close()
```

Please help me understand why i am so stupid that i can't figure this small problem out.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Downloads/scrape.py", line 74, in<module>
f.write(un + "," + deux + "," + trois + "," + quatre + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in    position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

*tears

Here is my updated script. Thank you all for the help!!!

```
            import bs4

            from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
            my_url = 'https://www.insertsitehere.com/'

            uClient = uReq(my_url)

            page_html = uClient.read()
            uClient.close()

            page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

            one = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"large-7 medium-9 columns"})
            two = page_soup.findAll("div",{"body field"})
            three = page_soup.findAll("div",{"field-ingredients-data field-wrapper"})
            four = page_soup.findAll("div",{"field-how-to-use-data field-wrapper"})



            uno = (one[0].h1)
            dos = two[1]
            tres = (three[0].p)
            cuatro = (four[0].p)


            filename = "example.csv"
            f = open(filename, "w",encoding="utf-8")

            headers = "one, two, three, four\n"
            f.write(headers)


            un = str(uno_en.text)
            deux = str(dos.text)
            trois = str(tres.text)
            quatre = str(cuatro.text)

            f.write(un + "," + deux + "," + trois + "," + quatre + "\n")

            f.close()
```

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: please modify your question to include the error format. Try to use the markdown editing so it is formatted correctly and easier to read.

Comment: Well that doesn't appear to have anything to do with a Unicode error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Downloads/scrape.py", line 74, in<module>
f.write(un + "," + deux + "," + trois + "," + quatre + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in    position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.8s]

Comment: I am sorry, I copied the wrong error

Comment: After `f = open(filename, "w")` what is `f.encoding`? You may want to be specific about the encoding `f = open(filename, "w",encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: @tdelaney YOUR A LIFESAVER!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
base.encode('utf-8)')
encoding_base.decode('utf-8)')
```

remove )

```
base.encode('utf-8')
encoding_base.decode('utf-8')
```

this is first that i see, but i need and error

somewhere in code you need to change `ingredrients` to `ingredients` check it

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Downloads/scrape.py", line 74, in<module>
f.write(un + "," + deux + "," + trois + "," + quatre + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in    position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.8s]

Comment: @ninodelaluna why you encode and then decode ? can you comment out decode and try to run script, also this error will be dispay? try `f.write(encoding_base)`

Comment: Currently, there are four items that I needed to scrape. un, deux, trois & quatre. Deux is where I assume there are characters that couldn't be decoded. The script will run fine without that, it is really weird.

Comment: Script was updated and now runs fine. Thanks for your help!